# How to centering of div who's display property may change?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to center google ads (doubleclick for publishers, adsense).

First I assumed they are going to use `display: block;` so I did `margin: 0 auto;`

It seems they are using `display: inline-block;` so I just used `text-align: center;`

Is there a solution that will help me sleep well at night, knowing it my ad centering won't change if they change display to something else one day?
Also that will work with other ad providers if they are using `display: block;` or other display type?

This is my code for now:

```
.ad {
  text-align: center;
  // & > div {
  //   display: inline-block;
  // }
}
```

It works without comments, but not sure if I should uncomment or not.

Ad code looks like this now, but can change.

```
<div class="ad" id="div-gpt-ad-id-censored" data-google-query-id="id-censored">
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('id-censored'); });
  </script>
  <div id="google_ads_iframe_/id-censored_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; display: inline-block; width: 234px; height: 60px;">
    <iframe style="border: 0px none; vertical-align: bottom;" src="http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-6/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/censored" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" data-is-safeframe="true" width="234" height="60" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, other ad providers might put anything else inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use well known trick `left` + `transform` attributes to center both of `block` and `inline-block`:

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
}
[class^="ad"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.ad1 {
  display: block;
  background: tomato;
}

.ad2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="ad1">advert1 display: block</div>
<div class="ad2">advert2 display: inline-block</div>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE

divs have not defined width and height

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
}
[class^="ad"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.ad1 {
  display: block;
  background: tomato;
}

.ad2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="ad1">advert1 display: block</div>
<div class="ad2">advert2 display: inline-block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Width and height of ads is unknown

Comment: no matter. it works whenever width is unknown or even not set. If width  is _not set_ it will keep default value `auto` and for block will expand to whole parent width, and for inline-block will be as wide as its content. Anyway it will be centered and you can sleep well

Comment: Why don't you remove width and height from answer then?

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look

Comment: Ok made it work. I don't know names of divs inside, so I had to select them using `cont > div`. I hope they will always keep it a div. If I put `cont > *` then script tags are also selected and made visible (their display is none by default).

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it by an own DIV which is set to display:inline-block always and have it centered.

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div class="ad-wrapper">
<div class="ad" id="div-gpt-ad-id-censored" data-google-query-id="id-censored">
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('id-censored'); });
  </script>
  <div id="google_ads_iframe_/id-censored_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; display: inline-block; width: 234px; height: 60px;">
    <iframe style="border: 0px none; vertical-align: bottom;" src="http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-6/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/censored" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" data-is-safeframe="true" width="234" height="60" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.ad-wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}

.outer-wrapper{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You want it to be centered _on the whole page_, I get it. Editing my answer

Comment: I can't have text align center on entire container, that will mess up my headers & paragraphs

Comment: I just added another container around the initial container, you can call it what you want. I'll make it more clear. In the outer-wrapper, you set text-align:center. In the inner-wrapper, you reset it to left. Try it out and then say whether it works or not.

Comment: Didn'you just wrap the problem into div called `.outer-wrapper`? `.outer-wrapper` will not be centered on the entire page unless I specify width & margin: 0 auto and I don't know the width.

Comment: Just try it and then tell me. .outer-wrapper is a block element so it will have full width. And _inside_ there is a smaller div called .ad-wrapper which is centered there.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I forgot to mention I want it centered on small screens only. This might work but I am going with other answer which doesn't require me to add 2 divs around original div.